# How to share variables between namespaces in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces, global-variables, static-members

I come from a C# background so I kindly ask the answers could compare to C#.

I have a namespace with functions and variables to parse input for my program. The namespace is defined in a header and a source file. I also have defined a struct which have one property for each input param in my program to facilitate communication across classes. Like the minimum working example below:

**mytypes.h**

```
#ifndef _MYTYPES_H_
#define _MYTYPES_H_
namespace MyTypes
{
    enum class Par1Opt
    {
        opt1,opt2
    };
    struct InputParam_t
    {
        Par1Opt par1;
        int test;
    };
}
#endif // _MYTYPES_H_
```

**myinput.h**

```
#ifndef _MYINPUT_H_
#define _MYINPUT_H_
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include "mytypes.h"
namespace MyInput
{
    static const std::string par1 = "par1";
    static int testVar;
    static MyTypes::InputParam_t inputParam;
    static std::unordered_map<MyTypes::Par1Opt, std::string> Par1OptToStr;
    void InitVariables(void);
}
#endif // _MYINPUT_H_
```

**myinput.cpp**

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include "mytypes.h"
#include "myinput.h"
namespace MyInput
{
    void InitVariables(void) // set some default values
    {
        inputParam.par1 = MyTypes::Par1Opt::opt1; // default value
        inputParam.test = 10;
        Par1OptToStr = std::unordered_map<MyTypes::Par1Opt, std::string>({
            { MyTypes::Par1Opt::opt1, "opt1" },
            { MyTypes::Par1Opt::opt2, "opt2" }
        });
        testVar = 20;
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myinput.h"
int main(int argCount, char* args[])
{
    MyInput::InitVariables(); // expect to set MyInput:: variables here
    std::cout << MyInput::par1 << " = "
        << MyInput::Par1OptToStr[MyInput::inputParam.par1]
        << std::endl; // par1 = 
    std::cout << "inputParam.test = " << MyInput::inputParam.test
        << std::endl; // inputParam.test = 0
    std::cout << "testVar = " << MyInput::testVar
        << std::endl; // testVar = 0
    std::cin.get(); // pause
    // none of the values set for the MyInput:: variables inside InitVariables() method
    // are available in main
}
```

The **questions** are:

1. Why are the values set inside `InitVariable()` not available in `main()`? Since the variables are static, I would expect (with mainly C# background) that the values would be available anywhere I use `#include "myinput.h"`. How can I solve it?
2. If I remove `static` keyword from variable declarations in `myinput.h`, then I get the `Multiply defined symbols` error. Why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suppose the two errors are related. A header file is literally copied to the including file whenever it's included. It means that if you define variables in it, they will get defined more than once. That's bad (hence the linker error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a global variable in .h file with `static` specifier, you create a separate variable in each translation unit in which the .h file is included, so the variables referenced in `myinput.cpp` are not the same as variables referenced from `main.cpp` despite they have the same names.

When you create it with no specifier, you violate [One Definition Rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).

What you should do is to declare variables with `extern` specifier in .h file and *define* them in one of .cpp files:

#### myinput.h

```
namespace MyInput
{
    extern const std::string par1;
    extern int testVar;
}
```

#### myinput.cpp

```
namespace MyInput
{
    const std::string par1 = "par1";
    int testVar;
}
```

Comment: the only variable which keeps its value is `par1` variable, maybe because it is declared as `const`?

Comment: @Girardi it's several variables, each having the same value. You can check it by taking its address.

Answer (score 2):

In C# every module automatically sees any symbol from any other module or source file it references, provided the symbol is accessible, `public` or internal.

In C++, however, that is not the case. Even if the variable you want to access is public and global, you still need an external declaration to be able to use it. For example:

#### file1.cpp

```
int global = 0;
```

#### file2.cpp

```
int main()
{
    global = 1; //error: undefined symbol `global`.

    extern int global; //a declaration, not a definition
    global = 2; //ok!
}
```

Now, writing an `extern` declaration inside a function, as I just did is considered bad practice. It is better to write them globally.

```
extern int global;

int main()
{
    global = 3; //ok;
}
```

Then, writing the `extern` declaration this way is also considered bad practice, because you have to copy it in every module that needs to use the variable. It is better to write that in a file and `#include` it:

#### file1.h

```
extern int global;
```

#### file2.cpp

```
#include "file1.h"
int main()
{
    global = 4; //ok;
}
```

Then, it is also good practice to `#include` this `.h` file in the definition of the variable, so that the compiler can check that the definition and the declaration are consistent:

#### file1.cpp

```
#include "file1.h"
int global = 0; //ok: definition and initialization

float global; //error: type mismatch
```

If the declaration in the `h` file were not marked as `external` it would actually be a definition, and you could end up with multiple definitions of the same symbol, and a compiler or linker error.

Remember that `#include` does not do any magic under the hood, it is just a textual inclusion of the referred file. The magic is actually in the linker, but that's another story...

Comment: More like, C++ has no modules (yet). The committee is working on it. But it's quite a more involved project than C#-modules, mainly due to the power of templates (compared to puny generics).